# convert an array to a list for spring

Tags: java, jackson

i use spring boot, jquery and spring rest controller

i try to save a list of object.

i sent to the server

```
{"defaultConfigDto":[{"fieldName":"","defaultConfigId":"","fieldValue":"0.2"},{"defaultConfigId":"","fieldName":"","fieldValue":"0.3"}]}
```

In my rest controller i have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tax", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Long saveTax(@RequestBody List<DefaultConfigDto> defaultsConfigs) {
    return defaultConfigService.saveTaxe(defaultsConfigs);
}
```

My DefaultConfigDto object

```
public class DefaultConfigDto {
    private Long defaultConfigId;
    private String fieldName;
    private String fieldValue;
}
```

In the server i see this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

My html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="defaultConfigDto[0].fieldName" name="defaultConfigDto[0].fieldName">
    <input type="hidden" id="defaultConfigDto[0].defaultConfigId" name="defaultConfigDto[0].defaultConfigId">
    <label for="tvqRate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tvq</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tvqRate" name="defaultConfigDto[0].fieldValue" placeholder="tax 1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" id="defaultConfigDto[1].defaultConfigId" name="defaultConfigDto[1].defaultConfigId">
     <input type="hidden" id="defaultConfigDto[1].fieldName" name="defaultConfigDto[1].fieldName">
     <label for="tpsRate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tps</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tpsRate" name="defaultConfigDto[1].fieldValue" placeholder="tax 2">
      </div>
</div>
```

what i need to modify to get only the list?

Comment: Should your json key be "defaultsConfigs"?

Comment: Your JSON looks like an object with a `defaultConfigDto` field, with the `defaultConfigDto` field being an array of `DefaultConfigDto` objects.  You may need to create a class `public class DefaultConfigs { private List<DefaultConfigDto> defaultConfigDto; }`.

Answer (score 1):

With your data like this:

```
{"defaultConfigDto":[{"fieldName":"","defaultConfigId":"","fieldValue":"0.2"},      {"defaultConfigId":"","fieldName":"","fieldValue":"0.3"}]}
```

Your @RequestBody type should be like this:

```
public Long saveTax(@RequestBody Map<String, List<DefaultConfigDto>> defaultsConfigs)
```